# Android Contextual Action Bar (CAB) backgroundSplit attribute not working

Tags: android, android-styles, contextual-action-bar

I am assuming the `backgroundSplit` attribute controls what is shown as the orange line on the bottom of the `CAB`:

[image: with backgroundSplit]

When I go to style my `CAB` and change the `background` color, the `backgroundSplit` disappears.

**styles.xml**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background</item> <!-- Here -->
</style>
```

**cab_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorSecondary"/>
</shape>
```

[image: without split]

The same thing happens if I set `actionModeBackground` as a `@color` resource instead of `@drawable`.

... and when I do this:

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item> <!-- Here -->
</style>

<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@drawable/cab_background</item>
</style>
```

I modeled my drawable after the one used in the `AppCompat` source code:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_material</item>
```

**abc_cab_background_top_material.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is a dummy drawable so that we can refer to the drawable ID -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

But, as the comment notes, this is just a dummy drawable, and I can't seem to find the one actually used. I'm starting to think that `backgroundSplit` does not actually refer to the orange line shown in the first picture and that the colored line is written directly into the drawable file, since in the source code `backgroundSplit` is set to a `@color/colorPrimaryDark` which is not the orange color shown. If so how would that drawable file look?

---

On the other hand, if `backgroundSplit` is in fact the attribute to manipulate, is this a bug in `AppCompat` or am I just using it wrong?

This does nothing I can see:

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@color/colorAccent</item> <!-- Here -->
</style>
```

... and neither does this:

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item> <!-- Here -->
</style>

<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@drawable/cab_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Doesn't matter if I set `backgroundSplit` to a `@drawable` either.